# How to have dropdown Search and textSearch (sharepoint project)

Tags: powerapps, sharepoint-list

**I have this code for the 3 dropdown and it works but i dont understand how to get the text Search to be added**

```
Filter(Möbler; 

Or(IsBlank(DropdownKategori.Selected); 
Kategori.Value = DropdownKategori.Selected.Value

&& 

IsBlank(DropdownSubKategori.Selected); 
SubKategori.Value = DropdownSubKategori.Selected.Value

&& 

IsBlank(DropdownColor.Selected); 
Color.Value = DropdownColor.Selected.Value

&& 

Bokad.Value = "Nej"
)
)
```

The start code for the project is

```
SortByColumns(Filter([@Möbler]; StartsWith(Title; TextSearchBox1.Text)); "Title"; If(SortDescending1; SortOrder.Descending; SortOrder.Ascending))
```

And can be shorten to .. i think

```
Filter([@Möbler]; StartsWith(Title; TextSearchBox1.Text)
```

Comment: If you want to give search feature you have use combo box instead of dropdown and enable searching

Comment: Dont understand . at default when i start its this code  ( SortByColumns(Filter([@Möbler]; StartsWith(Title; TextSearchBox1.Text)); "Title"; If(SortDescending1; SortOrder.Descending; SortOrder.Ascending)) )